# Weird UITextField glitch / bug: Cursor jumps left when centered text is deleted

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a weird glitch that occurs when I press the delete key in an empty UITextField.

I shouldn't be able to delete anything but the cursor moves over to the left about a tab width in the text field when I hit delete and it is empty.

This only happens when I have the text centered in the text field, not when it is left justified.

When I resume typing it jumps back to the center and behaves normally.

Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Check the UITextField content insets, maybe?

Comment: If the text is using the TextDescriptors, could it be deleting the one used to centring the text ? Are you using Text Kit at all ?

Comment: No - just a standard UITextField. : /

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution for this? I just noticed this issue myself.

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now!  Why hasnt anyone answered this!!? >:[

Answer (score 0):

In 2018 on XCode 9.3, and IOS 10.3...

I have verified that... at least in my case, the problem was being caused by the text field containing placeholder text.

When I removed the placeholder text, the cursor behaved "normally" / as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this isn't a very popular question, I just created an account to share my discovery regarding this problem.

The glitch/bug you're experiencing is caused by one line of code that you have (probably) added to your UITextField. No, it is not due to your UITextField containing a placeholder like the other answer suggested.

To fix this problem, the line you'll need to remove is

```
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing
```

Adding this line adds a clear button to the right side of your UITextField while it is being edited.

This causes your text to be shifted left by the size of the clear button, but only when the button is there (in this case, only while editing). This is why you may notice your text shifting back into the correct position when you have finished editing.

Hope this helps someone down the road!